# How to add a curve (smoothed line) to geom-bar in r?

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
for this data:

 big = runif(60);mangum = runif(61:120)
 df = data.frame(big, mangum)
 df_x <- eval(substitute(big), df)
 df_y <- eval(substitute(mangum), df)
 ccf.object <- ccf(df_x, df_y, plot = FALSE)
 output_table <- cbind(lag = ccf.object$lag, 
                    x.corr = ccf.object$acf) %>%
  as_tibble() %>%      mutate(cat = ifelse(x.corr > 0, "green", "red"))
 output_table %>%    ggplot(aes(x = lag, y = x.corr)) +
geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(fill = cat))
```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

How can add a smmothing curve above or below the bars like in the picture( bold line blue).

- geom_smooth() does not do what I need.

Comment: Does adding `+ geom_smooth()` to the end do what you want? Otherwise you'll need to describe in more detail what you're looking for

Comment: Not really, I need the curve to be really above the bars (when positive) and below (when negative).

Comment: @bicton do you mean you want a curve that touches the exact peak of each bar?

Comment: I added a picture of what I want.

Comment: @AllanCameron that might be yes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `stat_xspline` from `ggalt`:

```r
output_table %>%    
  ggplot(aes(x = lag, y = x.corr)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = paste0(cat, 3), color = after_scale(alpha(fill, 1))), 
           alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0) +
  ggalt::stat_xspline(spline_shape = -0.5, color = 'blue', linewidth = 1) +
  scale_fill_identity() +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Comment: @bicton yes. Just remove the `geom_col` line altogether.